# How to get same value in a unique column but differentiated by other column values?

Tags: mysql, index

I have a table like this

```
 ID | PRODUCT_NAME | MANUFACTURER_ID | PACKAGE_ID
---------------------------------------------------
  1 |   VITAMIN A  |       1         |      1
  2 |  PARACETAMOL |       2         |      1
```

`PRODUCT_NAME` must be unique for same manufacturer and same package ID, BUT it can be duplicate if manufacturer ID or Product ID are different.
I tried using UNIQUE but it is rejecting same values with different Manufacturer ID or Package ID

My desired output would be like :

```
 ID | PRODUCT_NAME | MANUFACTURER_ID | PACKAGE_ID
---------------------------------------------------
  1 |   VITAMIN A  |       1         |      1
  2 |  PARACETAMOL |       2         |      1
  3 |   VITAMIN A  |       2         |      1
```

Notice third value of `PRODUCT_NAME` 'VITAMIN A' is same but `MANUFACTURER_ID` is different.
Do we have any work-around for this other than UNIQUE?

Comment: Create a `UNIQUE` index on the combination of **both** product **and** manufacturer! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-) p.p.s. shown [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/).

Comment: Thanks alot, this solution saved me big time. I was going in a non ethical way. I tried to put Primary key on all except for main ID. So whenever I enter duplicate, it would throw me error. But your solution is very ethical and works best for me. Thanks alot again. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: I can write it up as an answer if you would like?

Comment: It seems you want a UNIQUE constraint/index on `(PRODUCT_NAME, MANUFACTURER_ID, PACKAGE_ID)`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, thats the solution.

Comment: @Vérace Thanks, but I did it. I had some other columns to add in constraints too, but these were main columns to consider.

Comment: Please, someone (Verace, Sushant) submit an answer. Sushant, it is fine to answer your own question. Extra points! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you were unaware that `UNIQUE` constraints can contain more than one field. Based on your question, I suggested 2 fields, i.e. both product **and** manufacturer.

It appears now (following comments) that 3 are required, as originally suggested by @ypercube.

From the link I originally posted [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/), the syntax you require is as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 'my_product_uq'  
ON my_product (product_name, manufacturer_id , package_id);
```